# Create a segmented control-like with a draggable function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have 2 divs positioned next to each other, and a background div. We'll call the background `div` "bg `div`". Whenever one of the 2 `divs` get selected, the bg `div` gets positioned on top of the selected `div` with a transition. Basically, something like a segmented controller.

The next step I want to do is, I want to make the bg `div` draggable. If it gets dragged, but not all the way to either side, then it should snap to whichever side the bg `div` is mostly at.

I'm looking for something like this:

[image]

When I set the bg `div` to be draggable, (using JQuery UI) it wasn't draggable. Only when I removed `z-index: -1` did it become draggable. It also didn't snap to either side. It only snapped when the bg `div` got dragged basically all the way. Also, when I drag it, it has a weird effect to it. It waits a bit then drags. I think that's because the transition.

**Problems**

- How can I make it draggable with of `index: -1`?
- How can I make it snap to whichever side the bg `div` is mostly at?
- How can I make it have a transition without working weird?

Without issues, but not draggable functionality: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fjq7Lms2/)

With issues: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7r0fqoh2/)

```js
$('#bckgrnd').draggable({
  axis: "x",
  containment: "parent",
  snap: ".labels"
});
```

```css
#radios {
  position: relative;
  width: 370px;
}
input {
  display: none;
}
#bckgrnd,
#bckgrndClear,
.labels {
  width: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.labels {
  outline: 1px solid green;
}
#bckgrnd {
  background-color: orange;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: left linear 0.3s;
}
#rad1:checked ~ #bckgrnd {
  left: 0;
}
#rad2:checked ~ #bckgrnd {
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="radios">
  <input id="rad1" type="radio" name="radioBtn" checked>
  <label class="labels" for="rad1">First Option</label>
  <input id="rad2" type="radio" name="radioBtn">
  <label class="labels" for="rad2">Second Option</label>
  <div id="bckgrnd"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is any reason not use existing plugin such as,
http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/?

Comment: @AdiDarachi I want to create it on my own.

Comment: @AdiDarachi Also, that's a switch, not a segmented control like the gif above

Comment: It was honest question, And I like the answer.

Comment: You can't use z-index:-1, if it is -1, you can't click on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/6j0538cr/ (I know you wont use it :))

**How can I make it draggable with of index: -1?**

- Add two elements one that hold the label with 'pointer-events:none;' which will ignore all mouse events and 'z-index:3',
  And second that will be the 'button' and will have 'z-index:1'.
  Like that you will have one label that ignores all mouse events and float above all the elements with z-index:3, and the 'background' will still be draggable

**How can I make it snap to whichever side the bg div is mostly at?**

- You can calculate it very easily using 'offset' and 'width' functions like so

  ```
  //calculating the middle of the 'background'
  var backgroundX = $('#bckgrnd').offset().left;
  var backgroundWidth = $('#bckgrnd').outerWidth();
  var backgroundMiddle = backgroundX + (backgroundWidth/2);

  //calculating the middle of the radios on the page
  var radiosX = $('#radios').offset().left;
  var radiosWidth = $('#radios').outerWidth();
  var radiosMiddle = radiosX + (radiosWidth/2);

  //compare the two
  if(radiosMiddle > backgroundMiddle){
      //closer to the left
  }else{
     //closer to the right
  }
  ```

**How can I make it have a transition without working weird?**

- You can set the transition using jQuery 'animate' instad of mixing css and js animation.

Comment: In the first step, you're saying I should have 4 labels all together?

Comment: Yes, two of them 'position:absolute;top:0;z-index:3;pointer-events:none;' that will hold the text, and two of them just like you did just without the text
check out the example: http://jsfiddle.net/6j0538cr/

Comment: did you got all the answers you seek?

Comment: Yes Thanks! Really like it!

Answer (score 0):

draggable with index -1: Have a container div for the whole thing (radios?) trapping mouse events. mousedown you record the mouse x value. mousemove (with button down I suppose) you calculate the "delta" from current mouse x to mousedown x, and add that to the original x value of the thing you are "dragging".

snapping: just using min / max function to limit the delta, but it sounds like some animation is there even for the "snap". So for a mouse up within a certain end zone range, fire that animation to "snap" to one side or the other.

Also, the click inside certain bounds close to the edge fires that same snap.

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: I don't think this is really trivial or quick. Where did you get that example image?

Answer (score 0):

I've could probably done this using `<input>` radio elements...
But any way on submit you can send the `data-*` value.

Here's my take:

[image]

```js
$(".io-toggler").each(function(){
  
  
  var io = $(this).data("io"),
      $opts = $(this).find(".io-options"),
      $clon = $opts.clone(),
      $span = $clon.find("span"),
      width = $opts.width()/2;
  
  $(this).append($clon);
  
  function swap(x) {
    $clon.stop().animate({left:  x}, 150);
    $span.stop().animate({left: -x}, 150);
    $(this).data("io", x===0 ? 0 : 1);
  }
  
  $clon.draggable({
    axis:"x",
    containment:"parent",
    drag:function(evt, ui){
      $span.css({left: -ui.position.left});
    },
    stop:function(evt, ui){
      swap( ui.position.left < width/2 ? 0 : width );
    }
  });
  
  $opts.on("click", function(){
    swap( $clon.position().left>0 ? 0 : width );
  });
  
  // Read and set initial predefined data-io
  if(!!io)$opts.trigger("click");
  // on submit read $(".io-toggler").data("io") value
  
});
```

```css
.io-toggler{
  cursor:pointer;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  font:20px/1.5 sans-serif;
  background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVCAQ.png);
  color:#fff;
  border:4px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 50px;
  user-select:none;
  -webkit-user-select:none;
  -webkit-touch-callout:none;
}
.io-options{
  border-radius:50px;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.io-options span{
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 3px 35px;
}

/* the jQ clone */
.io-options + .io-options{
  position:absolute;
  background:#fff;
  width:50%;
  height:100%;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
.io-options + .io-options span{
  color:#006cff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<span class="io-toggler" data-io="0">
  <span class="io-options">
    <span>Thing1</span>
    <span>Thing2</span>
  </span>
</span>

<br><br>

<span class="io-toggler" data-io="1">
  <span class="io-options">
    <span>Yes</span>
    <span>No</span>
  </span>
</span>
```